# Windows 10 as domain print server?

Tags: active-directory, windows-10, print-server

While it seems than win10 pro can expose a print server, I've tried to experiment a bit to understand if this print service can be used as a role in our domain.

Basically other machines *can* see the printer in the win10 machine if added via print management, but those printers are "volatile" (do not persist at reboot) and aren't pushed via GPO.

Before digging in possible errors on my side I would like to understand if I can use the service as in a win 2008 print server role.

Comment: No as you got winsock limitation too, so MS hardcode a limit in their workstation OS to prevent their use that way (as a server)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Workstation operating systems are not suited for server roles.

Comment: If so which is the min version of windows server capable of acting as a print srrver for say 30 users and 15 printers? Does essential fit the role? Thanx

Comment: You'll need to read the features of each product to determine which is correct.

Comment: Yeah done and I've not understood anything! Too much chaos with users/devices... Btw let close this here: better to open a proper call for help in sizing

Comment: @matteonunziati That's definitely small enough that any server OS would be able to handle it. I have, in the past, had larger print servers running from VMware Workstation on my laptop (for testing or proof of concept purposes).

Answer (score 0):

Its not good idea cause OS like Windows 10,8,7 are for simple users...what i mean is they cannot accept a lot of new TCP connections and will fail after a short of time, thats why you should use server OS like windows server 2012